# SQL Server WHERE clause with AND or OR

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have below search form which calls a stored procedure. Client requested a new feature which he needs to *Search Product **OR** Items*. To satisfy this new requirement I added a checkbox as in the image. If user check this checkbox, query should return either Products **OR** Items.

[image]

This is the existing query I used for the search,

```
Select * FROM PRODUCT P INNER JOIN ITEM I ON 
P.ID = I.PID

WHERE 

(@para_product_country is NULL OR @para_product_country = P.Country)
AND 
(@para_product_city is NULL OR @para_product_city = P.City)
AND
(@para_product_street is NULL OR @para_product_street = P.Street)

AND

(@para_item_country is NULL OR @para_item_country = I.Country)
AND 
(@para_item_city is NULL OR @para_item_city = I.City)
AND
(@para_item_street is NULL OR @para_item_street = I.Street)
```

How can I implement the query depending on users selection of checkbox which needs to search Products **OR** Items ? If user check the checkbox, query should return data either from Product **OR** Item. If user did not select the checkbox query should return data from Product **AND** Item.

I would like to know how to change the WHERE condition AND or OR according to checkbox selection ?

Comment: Sounds like you should have 2 queries, and your application runs the relevant query depending on the user input.

Comment: I suggest a read of [Catch-All Queries])https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: This type of query is unlikely to be very performant, I would consider this as several separate queries, capturing the resulting keys into a temp table and then returning required data (not * ) by joining from the temp table results.